# I want to know how to take information of checked checkboxin android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I-want-to-know-how to take information of checked checkbox to other 2 activities and and finally have an output display in textview in android studio

Answer (score 0):

You'll do better to share code of what you've tried to do already.

You can get the value of a checkbox to another activity with Intent by getting the checkstate with isChecked();